# Wordpress website migration from linux nginx to Windows Server2012

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, windows-server-2012, migrate

I really stuck and have no idea what to do. Please help me.

I am a Junior level developer and have close no experience in servers. I am the only one developer right now in company. Senior is out and have no answer to mail. We buy a dedicated server with Windows OS (Windows Server 2012). I connect remotely to Server and install IIS and try to download Microsoft Web Platform Installer 3.0 but I have no permission to download. What should I do? I have to download php and mySql. Generally that's what I found online. Maybe these are wrong. What should I do to transfer wordpress to windows server? Please help.

Comment: Try to install PHP5.6 which would contain PHP / Apache / Mysql on your server

Comment: Wherever you bought the dedicated server may have a help desk as well. GoDaddy helped me do quite a bit when I had some permission issues on a dedicated server at one time.